# Transient analysis with charged and uncharged inductor in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, inductance, transient

I have to do transient analysis in the following circuit.

When t<0.

L2 inductor is effectively bypassed and 10A flows through inductor L1.

At t = 0+
L1 behaves as a current source outputting 10A and L2 behaves as an open circuit.

I need the value for i(0+) to further solve the question. If I had to guess, I'd go with 0A because I feel like an open circuit is supposed to take priority over a current source.

[image]

Comment: Hm, if "L_2 behaves as an open circuit" and "L_1 behaves as a current source", you would be getting infinite voltage over L_2. And while that is a valid analytical result for an inifinitely short duration, it makes it impossible to say what happens in the time after t=0. So, you need to actually write down your differential equations and solve this, analytically, instead of just going by rules of thumbs.

Comment: Are the two inductor magnetically shielded?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The differential equations are unsolvable without knowing i(0+).

Comment: @Franc The question doesn't specify but let's assume they are coupled. What would i(0+) be?

Comment: @rjpj1998 be nice to your universe, assume i(t) to be differentiable ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do not follow :(. I can solve i(t) = Ae^(-5t) + 4 but to get the value of A I need i(0).

Comment: as said, assume i(t) is *differentiable*. You know i(0⁻).

Comment: What is the component shown in your diagram with an arrow across it. Question for the OP. And, despite your protests, your question body shows that you do know what i(0+) is.

Comment: The study with the Laplace transform is much simpler. Are you interested in studying the transient with this method?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i_L1(0-) is 10A and i_L2(0-) is 0A. At t=0+, L1 acts as a 10A current source and L2 acts as a 0A current source or a short. Which results in 2 current sources of different Amperage in series. This should be impossible. You can't know i(0+) from i_L1(0-) and i_L2(0-). https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138174/why-cant-different-current-sources-connect-in-series

Comment: you're so close. Now just *don't* go back to your unsuitable simplification how these things *should* behave.

Comment: @Andyaka the component is a switch of sorts. The connection is opened at t=0. I can assure you that I do not know what i(0+) is.

Comment: @Franc Laplace method will still require me to know what i(0+) is as L[i'(t)] = [sI(s) - i(0+)]

Comment: @MarcusMüller Honestly, I am in a crunch right now. I have my finals in <48 hrs. Could you please tell me what i(0+) is? If I had to guess, i'd go with 0A.

Comment: I mean, you spelled it out: your L1 tries to "push" 10 A. It will not suddenly stop doing so.

Comment: @MarcusMüller likewise, L2 will also resist any change in current. What if i_L2(0-) was somehow not 0, say 2A. What would i(t) be?

Comment: I give up. You're so far. You seem to have the system of differential equations linking current and voltage between the two inductors. Now just give up your incorrect rules of thumb and insert values as known.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Apologies. I didn't mean to bug you. Honestly we were simply taught to replace inductors with current sources and capacitors with voltage sources.

Comment: @rjpj1998 why not take the plunge and do what you are taught.

Comment: @Andyaka what we taught leads to a current source being connected to an open circuit.

Comment: Exactly, so, it's not solvable; the circuit is a fraud and will create infinite voltages; that's why I asked you about what you call a "switch of sorts". If it's something more like a switch in parallel with a resistor then it's solvable without dealing with infinities. Of course, your diagram is so faded that the so-called "switch of sorts" may not even make a connection at the top hence, it plays no role.

Answer (score 0):

The initial current seems distracting, The focus should be on the voltage aross \$L_2\$.

Place a resistor \$R_x\$ in parallel with \$L_2\$.

Pretend that \$L_1\$ is a current source for now.

The voltage across \$L_2\$ is \$V_{L2}=R_x I(0^+)\$

The current in \$R_x\$ decreases while the current in \$L_2\$ increases.

All of the current in \$R_x\$ transfers to \$L_2\$ in
\$5\frac{L_2}{R_x}\$ time constants as \$V_{L2}(0^+)\rightarrow 0\$

Set \$R_x=\text{TeraOhms}\$ to approximate removing it from the circuit. Then the duration of \$t=0^+\$ is pico-seconds. Take the \$\underset{R_{x}\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\$.

So now you should be able to determine \$I(0^+)\$ and \$V_{L2}(0^+)\$.

Now also \$L_2\$ stops being a current source a becomes an inductor again.